# Passing jQuery Variables to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an order form I'm working on, where I'm using jQuery to update the price in real time when the user selects different options. So, right now, the final project cost, package type, etc are set in jQuery variables, which I need to convert to PHP to insert into the database.

You can easily see the code: http://jsfiddle.net/cadengrant/uddPA/2/

And live preview of working code: http://www.htmlified.com/order-now/

```
function update_price() {
        var base_cost = base_price;
        var basic_price = base_price;
        var pro_price = base_price;

        jQuery('.packages .selected').each(function(index) {
            base_cost += jQuery(this).data("price");
            basic_price += base_cost;
            pro_price += base_cost + 70;
        });

        jQuery('#markup-pages').each(function(index) {
            var price = Number(jQuery(this).val());
            var packages = jQuery('.packages .selected').data("price");
            var pages = 0;

            jQuery('#packages .selected').each(function(index) {
                if(jQuery(this).hasClass('basic')) {
                    if(packages == 199) {
                        pages = price * 99 - 99;
                    } else if (packages == 189) {
                        pages = price * 94 - 94;
                    } else if (packages == 399) {
                        pages = price * 199 - 199;
                    }
                } else if (jQuery(this).hasClass('pro')) {
                    if(pro_price == 269) {
                        pages = price * 134 - 134;
                    } else if (pro_price == 259) {
                        pages = price * 129 - 129;
                    } else if (pro_price == 469) {
                        pages = price * 234 - 234;
                    }
                }
            });

            base_cost += pages;

            /* Single or plural page text */
            if(price == 1) {
                var markup_pages = "markup page";
            } else {
                var markup_pages = "markup pages";
            }
            jQuery('.markup-pages').text(markup_pages);
        });

        jQuery('#packages .selected').each(function(index) {
            if(jQuery(this).hasClass('pro')) {
                base_cost += 70;
            }
        });

        /* Update Doctype */
        jQuery('input[name=page_doctype]:checked', '#order-form').each(function(index) {
            var basic_doctype_text = "";
            var pro_doctype_text = "";
            if(jQuery(this).hasClass('doctypehtml')) {
                var doctype_text = "W3C Valid HTML5 & CSS3";
            } else if (jQuery(this).hasClass('doctypexhtml')) {
                var doctype_text = "W3C Valid XHTML1 & CSS2";
                basic_doctype_text += " Transitional";
                pro_doctype_text += " Strict";
            }

            jQuery('.doctype-text').html(doctype_text);
            jQuery('.basic-doctype').html(doctype_text + basic_doctype_text);
            jQuery('.pro-doctype').html(doctype_text + pro_doctype_text);
        });

        jQuery('.price').html(base_cost);
        jQuery('.basic-price').html(basic_price);
        jQuery('.pro-price').html(pro_price);
    }
```

I just need to figure out how to pass those variables (doctype text, basic doctype, pro doctype, base_cost, etc etc) in the JS section to my order.php form, so I can update amount paid, the package type they selected, etc. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can do it with AJAX request ..

Comment: i would populate hidden form fields with the jquery. they would be sent when the rest of the form is sent

Comment: Make an AJAX request to update a data-store to perform other operations

Comment: oh yes AJAX is the answer to every question, especially when you don't understand it. If you look at the preview, ajax would make things harder, there is already a form waiting for user input, so adding to that makes much more sense

Comment: @Dagon what? how is ajax not the solution??

Comment: @m59, see my comment below

Comment: Yeah, it's just not making any sense, at all.

Comment: this is a totally synchronous process, no need for an asynchronous approach, which actully makes things harder

Comment: @Dagon I must not have any clue what he is trying to accomplish.

Comment: Dagon, do you have an example of how to "populate hidden form fields with jquery?" Also, not all of the form is made using input fields.. some of the options are retrieved getting selected classes and assigning them to a jQuery variable..

Comment: your code shows you know how to write to the page with jquery, you do it exactly the same way if it a form a div or any other element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have a form in your page. I suggest you create hidden inputs in this form to be submitted with the form. Ex :

```
<input type="hidden" name="base_cost" value="999">
```

and you can adjust the value easily with jquery. After submitting the form to the php page you can capture these values using :

```
$base_cost = $_POST['base_cost'];
```

But don't forget to sanitize and validate every input from the user.
Hope this helps and excuse my English.

Comment: This does make sense to me.. however, not all of the options the user can select are created using inputs but rather divs. How would I do this with those divs considering the name attribute isn't valid for divs?

Comment: You can make jquery events in these divs which update the hidden inputs. Simply manipulating the DOM .

Comment: Alright.. makes sense.. off to Google to figure out how to do it. I accepted your answer but can't vote up due to my low reputation. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for a way to tell the Server information from the User? That my friend, without sending the form and without using ajax, will be hard :)

If I am understanding the issue properly, you want some parameters to change in Client side when user triggers some action. In that case you could load the possible parameters on page load and, when user triggers those actions, get the new parameters from those already loaded.
Then when you send the form you add to it the selected parameters.

Hope it helps!

Comment: That's extremely confusing... The price is stored in a variable base_cost... I need to pass base_cost to my order.php (what processes the form) so I can insert the final price (base_cost) into a variable so I can store it in the DB as well as send an email with the details.. including that price. Edit: Also, I didn't say I was opposed to using Ajax. I just have no idea how. These directions don't really help I'm curious in how to use Ajax to pass those variables.

Comment: who said not sending the form?

Comment: @CadenGrant again, put it in the form, in a hidden field it will then be in the post array with all the other form fields the user filled in and available on order.php

Comment: Can you show a basic example then? I'm a huge noob with jQuery and PHP... I just managed to find enough stackoverflow questions to figure out how to get the prices calculating as they are now.

Comment: I don't see how your confusion makes my answer less valuable (for the -1). If you are JQuery and PHP newbie and you're trying to use them, then that is not a question of "How to do that", is a matter of following some tutorials to learn the languages you want to apply. Then maybe my answer will not be so confusing for you.